# Azure Devops: Custom Condition to run task only if previous stage timed out

Tags: azure-devops

I have a stage in my azure devops release pipeline that should only run if the previous stage timed out as intended.  I have the following release pipeline:

- stage 1: Deploy

  - create stage app service slot
  - deploy to stage app service slot
- stage 2: Swap slots

  - Pending approval: swap app service stage slot to production
- stage 3: Rollback

  - Pending approval: swap production back to stage
- stage 4:

  - Delete stage slot

I have stage 3 configured to a timeout of x days.  It exists as a quick approve and roll back as necessary.  The thing I am trying to get working, is if the timeout triggers on stage 3, a custom condition on stage 4 triggers the deletion of the now unneeded stage slot.

Comment: Hello! Please check in task 'Control Options' > ' Run this task' setting called "Only when a previous task has failed."

Comment: Does a cancel/timeout count as a failure?  Thought it might not but I'll test it out.  Though I'm thinking I'm using the timeout option incorrectly anyways

Comment: I think timeout should be count as a failure:)

In releases where i need to wait on something at backend etc.. I use dummy step which is just a timer. After that I place right script or code which will finish succesfully or fail, and then it's possible to handle this.

Comment: It makes it easier when you want to rerun your relase from particular place and for example just skip timeout.

Comment: I like this idea.  The timeout I turned on in under the approver section doesn't actually cancel/fail the stage, it just times out the approvals.  So a dummy step would take care of it.  Then I could do like I did see in another post and output a variable to use on a custom condition to run the delete section.

Comment: Hi, glad to hear that you have solved your issue! Could you post your solution here and mark it, so that people with similar issue can find a solution more easily. Thank you~